# after importing to unity a face disappears

Tags: faces, normals, unity

In blender the normals are all on the correct side: 
[image: image in blender]

But when i import to unity it disappears: 
[image: image in unity]

I need it to appear, since this is the broken box model, so it will show all faces. 
I've seen other posts similar problems but it didn't solve mine.

extra info: all objects are applied to position, rotation, and scale.

Comment: thats not blender question. more like a unity question.

Comment: try flipping that face normal and see what happens in unity, will it still not show up? also try select all and press `m` > merge by distance